# CSS: why is :hover applied to the whole website and not only to the <div> element it is applied to?

Tags: javascript, html, css

have this problem as stated in description.
I would like, that the `:hover` effect would be applied only to the parent element and its children, and not to the entire website.

Tried to add pointer-events to none, but it did not help. Also the effect is on the parent but not the sibling, as advised in other questions, but it also did not help.

Here is my code:

App.js:

```
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="parent">
        <div className="child1">child1</div>
        <div className="child2">child2</div>
      </div>
      <div className="sibling">sibling</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

CSS:

```
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.parent::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 3px;
  background-color: #1a38e2;
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
  transform: scaleY(0);
  -webkit-transition: width 0.4s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0, 1) 0.2s,
    background-color 0.1s, -webkit-transform 0.2s;
  transition: width 0.4s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0, 1) 0.2s, background-color 0.1s,
    -webkit-transform 0.2s;
  transition: transform 0.2s, width 0.4s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0, 1) 0.2s,
    background-color 0.1s;
  transition: transform 0.2s, width 0.4s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0, 1) 0.2s,
    background-color 0.1s, -webkit-transform 0.2s;
}

.parent:hover::before {
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
  transform: scaleY(1);
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

I also have an SCSS, but do not know, how to deal with it on codesandbox, but I apply it anyway:

SCSS

```
.parent::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 3px;
  background-color: #1a38e2;
  transform: scaleY(0);
  transition: transform .2s, width .4s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0, 1) .2s,
    background-color .1s;
}

parent::before {
  transform: scaleY(1);
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Link to my codesandbox: [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/csshoveroverparentonly-0nstl?file=/src/styles.scss:0-329)

And am, as always, very happy about any help provided.

Comment: Hovering `.parent` makes it change its size to the entire document, so leaving its children won't matter, you're still hovering `.parent`. Add `.parent { position: relative; }` so the `height: 100%` applies to that, not `body`. [fixed](https://codesandbox.io/s/csshoveroverparentonly-forked-egd2r?file=/src/styles.css)

Comment: Well thanks a lot, that is the solution. Could you write is as an answer so that I could mark it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give position relative to div

```
.parent div {
  position: relative;
}
```

instead of

```
parent::before
```

use this

```
   .parent div::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 3px;
  background-color: #1a38e2;
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
  transform: scaleY(0);
  -webkit-transition: width 0.4s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0, 1) 0.2s,
    background-color 0.1s, -webkit-transform 0.2s;
  transition: width 0.4s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0, 1) 0.2s, background-color 0.1s,
    -webkit-transform 0.2s;
  transition: transform 0.2s, width 0.4s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0, 1) 0.2s,
    background-color 0.1s;
  transition: transform 0.2s, width 0.4s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0, 1) 0.2s,
    background-color 0.1s, -webkit-transform 0.2s;
}

.parent div:hover::before {
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
  transform: scaleY(1);
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```